# Can you sell utility bots created with RPA softwares by publishing it to their marketplaces?

Tags: automation, rpa, uipath, automationanywhere

I am looking to get my hands dirty on RPA softwares called Automation Anywhere and UI Path. Does it make sense to develop these bots, upload to their marketplace utility stores for some earning? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What you want to accomplish? Is it some general stuff or is your plan to develop some UiPath Go! extentions? https://go.uipath.com/

Comment: tbh im not sure at this point, I can grasp how to make things that go to their market places. @kwoxer

Comment: Before you do anything, you should definitely go through the whole UiPath Acedemy. Otherwhise your developed Go! will be not of high quality.

Comment: sure, thanks @kwoxer